# Is there another way, other than the "depends_on" list, for a Property to become a dependency of another Property?

Tags: python, enthought

In the Enthought Traits/UI system, is there another way, other than being included in another Property's *depends_on* list, that a Property can become a dependency of another Property?

I have a *HasTraits* subclass, which has a property, *chnl_h*, which doesn't appear in any other Property's *depends_on* list, but is behaving as if it were a dependency of another Property. That is, it is recalculating its value, whenever one of its dependencies changes value, as opposed to only when its value is actually requested.

Thanks!
-db

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this directly answers your question, but you may get what you're after by using the `@cached_property` decorator to reduce the number of time the property is computed.  I think there may be elements of "push" and "pull" style computations with properties.